# How to handle variation of min_rank in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

I have the following `data.frame`

```
df

id  name  strength days date
1   a     10       20   10
1   a     10       30   11
1   a     10       10   12
1   a     5        20   14
1   a     5        10   15
1   a     10       20   16
2   b     10       15   09...
```

I need to find the sum of days for each group of `id` having a continuous usage of the combination of name and strength. eg. Expected outcome

```
id  name  strength sumOfDays
1   a     10       60
1   a     5        30
1   a     10       20
```

I was trying out `min_rank` for the same using :

```
y <- df %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  mutate(group = min_rank(strength ))
```

which gives me an unwanted grouping (correct logically) as it groups all a-10 together but does not consider the ordering of date :

```
df
id  name  strength group
1   a     10       3
1   a     10       3
1   a     10       3
1   a     5        1
1   a     5        1
1   a     10       3
2   b     10       1...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `rleid` function from the `data.table` to create the column for grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(id, name, strength, Group = rleid(strength)) %>%
  summarise(sumOfDays = sum(days)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(id, Group) %>%
  select(-Group)
dat2
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      id name  strength sumOfDays
#   <int> <chr>    <int>     <int>
# 1     1 a           10        60
# 2     1 a            5        30
# 3     1 a           10        20
# 4     2 b           10        15
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id  name  strength days date
1   a     10       20   10
                  1   a     10       30   11
                  1   a     10       10   12
                  1   a     5        20   14
                  1   a     5        10   15
                  1   a     10       20   16
                  2   b     10       15   09",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` version with `rle` and `aggregate`

```
rl <-  rle(dat$strength)
aggregate(days ~., transform(dat, Group = rep(seq_along(rl$values), 
              rl$lengths))[-5], FUN = sum)[-4]
#   id name strength days
#1  1    a       10   60
#2  1    a        5   30
#3  1    a       10   20
#4  2    b       10   15
```